# Function to create a list from vector data (dictionary) with indices and values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that will use a vector data structure `a` which stores indexes and values, and converts it into a new list.  The new list will also sum up all the values with the duplicate indexes.  In addition, `a` can be any length.

For example:

```
a = {'index': [], 'value': []}
a['index'] = [0,   2,   7,   2,   2,   5, 1]
a['value'] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 8.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

The desired output would be :

```
x = [1.0, 7.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 3.0]
```

where for index 2, it would sum up to 14 (2, 4, and 8).  For any index that doesn't appear in `a['index']`, it would be assigned `0` in `x`.

I'm trying iterate `a[index,values]` over a new `x` line with zero values of length `n`. If the `x[i]` already exists, it would sum onto the existing value.  I know my for statement is a little off, but I'm not sure how to fix it syntactically:

```
def newlist(a, n=None):
    i_max = max(a['index']) if a['index'] else -1
    if n is None:
        n = i_max+1
    else:
        assert n > i_max, 

    x = [0] * n
    for i, v in zip(a['index'], a['value']):
        if x[i] in a['index']:
            x[i]+=v
        else:
            x[i]=v
    return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list already contains zeros so you can always just add the value (because `0+v` is the same as setting it to `v`). With that modification the function would look like this:

```
def newlist(a, n=None):
    i_max = max(a['index']) if a['index'] else -1
    if n is None:
        n = i_max+1
    else:
        assert n > i_max

    x = [0] * n
    for i, v in zip(a['index'], a['value']):
        x[i] += v
    return x
```

And it returns what you expect:

```
>>> newlist(a)
[1.0, 7.0, 14.0, 0, 0, 6.0, 0, 3.0]
```

There's one difference to the desired output, the integer `0` is used instead of the float `0.`. That can easily be fixed by replacing `x = [0] * n` with `x = [0.] * n`.

On a more general note:

You should use more meaningful variable names like `dct` instead of `a` and what `n` should mean is just beyond me. A function named `newlist` isn't very informative either.